# Controlling the control flow tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I recently added *Usage Guidance* and the first version of a tag wiki for [control-flow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-flow). A few (about 6) questions using this tag actually refer to the similarly-named but distinct concept of [terminal flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_control_(data)). I thought I’d ask on Meta for advice on what to do with these questions. The options I’ve considered so far are:

1. simply edit the questions to remove the [control-flow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-flow) tag (there are only a few of them)
2. create a [flow-control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flow-control) and re-tag the questions – the name is short but could be easily confused with [control-flow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-flow)
3. create a [terminal-flow-control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal-flow-control) – avoids confusion with [control-flow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-flow)

Comment: My 2 cents: replace that tag with "terminal" if it's not there already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed Jeff’s advice and edited just **five** questions to remove the [control-flow](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/control-flow) tag and replace it with [terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminal) if the question wasn’t already tagged as such.